# Adding inductance in order to make AC offset

Tags: capacitor, inductor, passive-networks, pspice, voltage-source

everybody

The task was to introduce a 10 MHz AC signal to the output along with the 24 DC voltage.
If I directly connect DC to the circuit, at the output (*75 Ohm resistor*) I get the straight line => I don't want that.

[image: Circuit without L2]
[image: Simulation without L2]

However, **as soon as I put an inductance** between the DC source and the rest of the circuit I got the desired result.

[image: Circuit with L2]
[image: Simulation with L2]

I can't figure out the reason behind this change. I feel it's some basic stuff, and it seems like an explanation is on the tip of my tongue but I can't derive it XD

Comment: It seems like without L2, the 10 MHz signal goes not through L1 but to the source V2. Adding L2 leaves the only path for AC signal => through the L1 do the load R3. Is it correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 24V battery short-circuits the incremental signal so the voltage on R3 is exactly 24V, once the transient is over. The insertion of the inductance L2 allows the passage of direct current but presents a very high reactance to incremental signals so they are not short-circuited by the battery. The voltage on R3 now consists of a direct voltage on which an incremental signal is superimposed which is obtained by studying the L1+R2//C3 network.